# How to set IPv6 RA values for RDNSS and DNSSL on HPE/Aruba 5400R

Tags: router, ipv6, hp-procurve, aruba

I am detail-planning the roll out of IPv6 in our company.
Right now I am stuck with IPv6 RA on our HPE/Aruba Access Switches. I cannot find any documentation how to set the Recursive DNS Server (RDNSS) and DNS Search List (DNSSL) values in the RA.

I expected a command like `ipv6 nd ra rdnss <ip6-of-rdnss>`, but there's nothing like that.

The "HPE ArubaOS-Switch IPv6 Configuration Guide" only has the following information concerning this:

> DNS options are included by default in every emitted RA unless the
>   inclusion is suppressed via CLI commands or the SNMP MIB.

So my question is: how do I configure the RDNSS/DNSSL values in my RAs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it turns out this cannot be configured in a sane manner.
Both values are taken from the configuration of the DNS resolver and search-list for the *management plane* of the switch.

This implies that you cannot set different values on different interfaces and you cannot set different values for your management network.